# Verb for "friction"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Many languages have a verb to describe friction between two objects e.g. The door xxxx the carpet. Is there a similar way to say so in English rather than "There is friction between the door and the carpet"? I guess "fricts" is not a word :)

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?  this would help you.  The best word with doors on a carpet or similar surface is ‘brush’ because the surface is most like the bristles of a soft brush.  So a door “brushes” across a carpet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to **rub**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rub)

> To apply pressure and friction to (a surface).

As in:

> The door rubs the carpet.

to **scrape** is a close second choice.

Comment: Scrape would be for a hard surface, tho.

Comment: @Wordster or a hard object, especially if the pile on the carpet is shallow

Answer (score 0):

There's no verb for word friction (noun). It's an exception in English grammar. However, there's an explanation to this action (verb) ie to rub (against each other).

Comment: "to rub" was already given as an answer.

Comment: Hello, Urvashi. Grammar deals with how words are conventionally assembled to make  intelligible passages; the study of the meaning of individual words (and lacunas) is classed under semantics.